# Why is the suggested "belongs to another stackexchange site" list so limited?

Tags: support, migration

I just wanted to flag [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255780/how-do-you-prove-this-algorithm-is-optimal) question as offtopic. I wanted to suggest that it belongs to cstheory.stackexchange.com. Unfortunately, I can't, because it's not on the possible target StackExchange sites list. Why is there no "other" button?

Comment: Because we "don't migrate crap" and tons of crap got migrated. Also, other sites (I'm lookin' at you, Programmers) started getting used as a trashcan.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar But I miss my trash can. :(

Comment: If it is an outstanding question that just happens to be on the wrong site, use the "Flag" tool and choose the "Other" option. Explain why the question should be migrated. Moderators can migrate to any site.

Comment: @AlEverett The problem with that approach is that it can take weeks until the migration happens if you're unlucky.

Comment: Be that as it may, that's currently the correct process.